# Prometheus setting for scrape_interval

Tags: prometheus, victoriametrics

I'm trying to use Prometheus and VictoriaMetrics to collect data and when configuring my server prometheus.yml there is one line:

```
scrape_interval: 15s  # How frequently to scrape targets by default.
```

Does this mean my search result might be delayed by 15s?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, this means that at worst, your metrics will arrive 15 seconds later. You can configure it to be faster.

`<duration>: a duration matching the regular expression [0-9]+(ms|[smhdwy])`

The above is from the Prometheus docs at: https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/#duration

Typically, think of it as Prometheus taking snapshots of what your (continuous) metrics look like (CPU used, no. of threads running etc.) instead of thinking of Prometheus as a place to collect discrete events.

When you are thinking of how long your alert will take to fire, or for the data to be visible, the scrape interval is a factor to keep in mind.

In the context of alerting, a good resource is this article: https://pracucci.com/prometheus-understanding-the-delays-on-alerting.html

It basically says that if your scrape interval is `x` time unit, and you only fire an alert if an expression is true for `y` time unit, then the delay could at worst be (x + y) time units.